# ruby delete hash of hash based on identical values for different keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash of hashes like this:

```
authors = {"7"=> {"id"=>"60"} , "0"=> {"id"=>"60"} , "1"=> {"id"=>"99"}, "8"=> {"id"=>"99"}, "15"=> {"id"=>"19"} }
```

I want to merge each hash where the id of the hash in that hash is duplicated (or remove each second hash with same hash of hash id).

In this case, I want to end up with

```
authors = {"7"=> {"id"=>"60"} , "1"=> {"id"=>"99"}, "15"=> {"id"=>"19"}}
```

There are quite a few questions on sorting hashes of hashes, and I've been trying to get my head around this, but I don't see how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways.

**#1**

```
require 'set'

st = Set.new
authors.select { |_,v| st.add?(v) } 
  #=> {"7"=>{"id"=>"60"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"99"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"19"}}
```

**#2**

```
authors.reverse_each.with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[v] = k }.
  reverse_each.with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[v] = [k] }
  #=> {"7"=>[{"id"=>"60"}], "1"=>[{"id"=>"99"}], "15"=>[{"id"=>"19"}]}
```

or

```
authors.reverse_each.to_h.invert.invert.reverse_each.to_h
```

Comment: This version should be far more efficient than mine. I thought about it too after I wrote my version.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
authors.to_a.uniq { |item| item.last["id"] }.to_h
 => {"7"=>{"id"=>"60"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"99"}, "15"=>{"id"=>"19"}}
```

`uniq` method with a block can do the work